# Distinguishing between indirect objects and circumstantial complements

Tags: verbos, pronombres, preposiciones, objetos-indirectos

According to [this](https://open.books4languages.com/spanish-a2-grammar-en/chapter/complementos-del-verbo/), a verb can take complements of four different types: attribute, direct complement, indirect complement (IC), and [circumstantial complement](https://open.books4languages.com/spanish-a2-grammar-en/chapter/complementos-circustanciales/).

I sometimes have trouble distinguishing between an indirect complement and a circumstantial complement (or maybe not a complement at all). Thanks to SE, I think I am getting more comfortable with this (especially with circumstantial complements of place), but I still don't feel super-confident.

**Can anyone give me some examples of cases where it is difficult for a beginner to tell whether something is an indirect complement or a circumstantial complement (or maybe not a complement at all)?**

For example, I think the following sentence is correct: "Envié una carta al buzón." I have been told that "al buzón" is a circumstantial complement because it answers the question "to where is the letter being sent?". That makes sense to me, but seems tricky because it could also answer the question "to what is the letter being sent"? Maybe you don't think this is a tricky example; that's fine. I'm looking for **your** tricky examples.

Comment: Perhaps you should take this one step at a time.  I think you are biting off more than you can chew. Unless these things are learned step by step, they can be overwhelming.

Comment: Can you recommend any beginner-level lessons or references that place a heavy emphasis on grammar and on "unusual cases"/"exceptions"?

Comment: Right now I'm working along two very separate tracks: one the one hand, I am doing some pretty linear, beginner-friendly lessons that focus on common situations. On the other hand, I'm asking all these annoying and uninformed questions on SE to try to get the bigger picture. I would be more comfortable laying off the annoying questions if I felt confident that my lessons were going to **explicitly** cover unusual cases. I think most people's teaching philosophy is that those are "advanced" topics to be covered later. But I just can't stay engaged that way.

Comment: The Instituto Cervantes is the best place to learn Spanish: https://nyork.cervantes.es/en/classes_spanish/spanish_classes.htm I don't know where you are located but you can do a course online.

Comment: Thanks @Lambie! How much do you think they deal explicitly with grammatical rules and unusual cases at lower levels?

Comment: https://www.ucm.es/plataformaele/complemento-circunstancial If you can understand that, good luck. :)

Comment: Thanks @Lambie. I'll try to read it in Spanish so I get some "real-world" education along with my "weird question" education. I appreciate your help, both with my questions and your more general wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se denomina complemento circunstancial, a la función sintáctica desempeñada por un sintagma adverbial, por un sintagma nominal o por un sintagma preposicional, que señale alguna circunstancia semántica de tiempo, lugar o modo al verbo del que es complemento. A veces incluso cantidad, causa o finalidad de alguna acción.

> The syntactic function performed by an adverbial phrase, a nominal
> phrase, or a prepositional phrase that indicates some semantic
> circumstance of time, place, or manner to the verb of which it is a
> complement is called a circumstantial complement. Sometimes even
> quantity, cause or purpose of some action.

Sobre los Complementos Circunstanciales (CC) en español

> About Complementos Circunstanciales (CC) in Spanish

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemento_circunstancial

Estos es un pequeño resumen, ya que cada complemento tiene sus propias circunstancias y explicar esto de forma escrita es largo y laborioso.

> This is a short summary, since each plugin has its own circumstances
> and explaining this in writing is long and laborious.

La frase "**Envié una carta al buzón**" no es problemática ya que "al buzón" no es un complemento indirecto y por tanto no puede surgir duda. "Al buzón" sería un "complemento de lugar" ¿*donde*?.

La duda puede surgir por ejemplo entre;

> Doubt may arise, for example, between;

- El ha comprado unas flores **para Margarita**.

¿Qué es para Margarita? ¿Complemento Indirecto o Complemento de Finalidad?

> What is it **para Margarita**? ¿Complemento Indirecto o Complemento de
> Finalidad?

Algunos autores dicen que es un Complemento Indirecto ya que se puede decir;

- El ha comprado unas flores **a Margarita**.

Sin embargo, la mayoría piensa que es un Complemento de Finalidad.

> Some authors say that it is an "Complemento Indirecto" since it can be
> said;
>
> - El ha comprado unas flores **a Margarita**.
>
> However, most think that it is a "Complemento de Finalidad".

---

**Trucos**

Hay que recordar que en una frase puede existir a la vez un complemento indirecto (CI) y otro tipo de complemento circunstancial (CC).

> It must be remembered that in a sentence there can be both an
> "complemento indirecto" (CI) and another type of "complemento
> circunstancial" (CC).

Imaginemos la siguiente frase;

> Let's imagine the following sentence;

- (Ellos) han comprado una moto a su amiga.

(Ellos) = **S**ujeto / han comprado = **V**erbo / una moto = CD / a su amiga = CI

En estos casos de duda con el CC de Finalidad, si el Complemento Indirecto (CI) lo ponemos delante del verbo lo que hace **el español es repetirlo de manera pronominal** con le / les

> In these cases of doubt with the CC Finalidad, if we put the Complemento Indirecto
> (CI) before
> the verb, what **Spanish does is repeat it pronominally** with le / les.

En la frase

- (Ellos) han comprado una moto a su amiga.

pasamos el CI delante del verbo

> we pass the CI before the verb

- **A su amiga** **le** han comprado una moto.

"**A su amiga**" = CI / "**le**" = CI  - El CI aparece duplicado /

> CI appears duplicate.

En el caso de tener un complemento con "**para**", cuando lo ponemos delante del verbo no existe duplicación, es decir, con **"para**" no se repite ningún pronombre.

> In the case of having a complement with "**para**", when we put it
> before the verb there is no duplication, that is, with "**para**" no pronoun is
> repeated.

Escribamos una frase con "**para**".

> Let's write a sentence with "**para**".

- (Yo) He comprado unas bombillas para su coche.

(Yo) = S. / he comprado = V. / unas bombillas = CD / para su coche = CC Finalidad

Si el CC de Finalidad "**para**" lo ponemos delante del verbo;

> If the CC Finalidad "**para**" we put it before the verb;

- **Para su coche** he comprado unas bombillas.

No hay duplicación. No se repite ningún pronombre. Por tanto no es complemento indirecto y es complemento de finalidad.

> There is no duplication. No pronoun is repeated.
>
> Therefore, it is not an CI and is a CC de Finalidad

Así en el primer ejemplo;

> So in the first example;

- Ha comprado unas flores para Margarita

Ponemos "**para**" delante del verbo para ver si tenemos duplicación y vemos que

> We put "para" before the verb to see if we have duplication and we see
> that

- **Para** Margarita ha comprado unas flores.

Tampoco hay duplicación o repetición. Por tanto es complemento de finalidad

> There is also no duplication or repetition. Therefore, it is a complemento de
> finalidad.

---

**Otra manera a tener en cuenta.**

> **Another way to keep in mind.**

**El Complemento Circunstancial de Finalidad (CCF), introducido por "para" lo podemos sustituir por pronombres "Tónicos" (ayer escribí una respuesta mencionándolos), yo, tú, él, nosotros, vosotros, ellos, mientras que el Complemento Indirecto (CI) siempre va a ser sustituido por pronombres "Átonos", en este caso "le/les".**

> **The Complemento Circunstancial de Finalidad (CCF), introduced by "para" can be
> replaced by "Tónicos" pronouns (yesterday I wrote an
> answer mentioning them), yo, tú, él, nosotros, vosotros, ellos, (I,
> you, he, we, you, they), while the Complemento Indirecto (CI) will
> always be replaced by "Átonos" pronouns, in this case "le/les".**

En el siguiente ejemplo

> In the following example

- He comprado unas flores a Ramón para Margarita.

Al sustituir por los pronombres Átonos y Tónicos, la oración quedaría;

> By substituting for the Átonos and Tónicos pronouns, the sentence
> would remain;

- **Le** he comprado unas flores para **ella**.

Así podemos encontraros con un CI y CCF juntos

**Le** = CI Pronombre Átono.

para **ella** = CCF con Pronombre Tónico.